# Code splitting `import` breaks Jest tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, webpack, jestjs

I'm using the code splitting feature of webpack, but it seems that jest doesn't recognize the `import()` function:

```
        import('myModule').then(function (myModule) {
        ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

I don't have any special setup. My npm test script is simply run jest `"test": "jest"`

How can I make it work?

I'm using the latest version of jest 20.0.4 and babel-jest 20.0.3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Oh I just found the answer.

Simply install this plugin: https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node and add it to the `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  ...
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["dynamic-import-node"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've been having the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45023155/webpack-code-splitting-breaks-jest-import-with-vuejs-components/45042067#45042067), this solved my problem, thanks! Although I also had to run jest in --no-cache mode at all times for it to work :/

Comment: Note that if you're using Jest with Typescript through ts-jest, then this configuration needs to be added to 
```{
  ...
  "jest": {
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "babelConfig": {
          "env": {
            "test": {
              "plugins": ["dynamic-import-node"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}```

Comment: @DmitriyT hi Dmitry, where to add the configuration that you mention? .babelrc or to jest config?