# Can't test a function with a dynamic import with Jest and babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babeljs, jestjs, dynamic-import

I'm trying to test the following function:

```
export async function loadLocale(language) {
  return await import(`./locales/${language}.json`)
}
```

With the following code:

```
import * as utils from '@/langs/utils'

describe('language utils to interact with vue-i18n', () => {
  it('should load a given locale from file', async () => {
    const language = 'es'
    expect.assertions(1)
    const locale = await utils.loadLocale(language)
    expect(locale).toEqual({ foo: 'bar' })
  })
})
```

I have installed [babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node](https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node) because the dynamic imports don't work in Node and must be replaced with require.

This are the contents of the `es.json` I try to load:

```
{
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

My `.babelrc` config is as follows:

```
{
  "presets": [
  "@vue/app"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "syntax-dynamic-import"
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["dynamic-import-node"]
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my folder structure:

```
│   ├── langs
│   │   ├── i18n.js
│   │   ├── locales # Actual locales
│   │   │   ├── en.json
│   │   │   └── es.json
│   │   └── utils.js
├── tests
│   └── unit
│       ├── langs
│       │   ├── locales # Mocked locales
│       │   │   ├── en.json
│       │   │   └── es.json
│       │   └── utils.spec.js
```

As I'm using the configuration provided by vue-cli I've tried running Jest with the `--no-cache` flag as [this answer mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44643340/code-splitting-import-breaks-jest-tests).

The error I get is the following:

```
Cannot find module 'function () {
                return require("./locales/".concat(language, ".json"));
              }' from 'utils.js'

  11 | }
  12 |
> 13 | export async function loadLocale(language) {
  14 |   return await import(`./locales/${language}.json`)
  15 | }
  16 |

  at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:169:17)
  at src/langs/utils.js:13:8
```

Which doesn't make sense, because `./locales/es.json` exists! And moreover, i've tried using require with the exact same route from the test and it loads correctly it's contents.

Any ideas?

Comment: What a weird error. That makes it sound like it literally took the string content of the function itself (not the `./locales` path), and tried to look for that as the name of a file.

Comment: @loganfsmyth  you're right. That's exacly what is happening. Plugin tries to resolve something that already has been changed from `import` into `require`

Answer (score 0):

You use `dynamic-import-node` plugin twice. I did the same with

```js
"presets": [
    "react-app",
],
```

See [vue-cli/packages/@vue/babel-preset-app/index.js](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/14181785666e48af9dd34531acd0323f9a420716/packages/@vue/babel-preset-app/index.js#L123)

Comment: What did you mean by this? I can only see `dynamic-import-node` being imported once. Maybe the code has changed. I have exactly the same problem as above. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Plugin is already added in preset.
Yes, the code changed. I should've provide link to specific commit:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/14181785666e48af9dd34531acd0323f9a420716/packages/@vue/babel-preset-app/index.js#L123